# Error con una petición HttpCliente en ionic 3

Tags: typescript, ionic3

Tengo el siguiente problema cuando hago una petición `get` con `HttpClient` y lo pongo correr en Android funciona bien, pero cuando lo pongo a emular en IOS la petición falla. Pero cuando utilizo el HTTP de ionic-native si funciona.

Aquí esta el código del provider:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { URL } from '../../util';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';
/*
  Generated class for the ParkingProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class ParkingProvider {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}

  getAllParking(){
    return this.http.get(URL);
  }

}
```

> Me dijeron que podia ser por permisos en IOS  agregue el permiso en el
>   config.xml pero a un sigue igual

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué error te da?